# Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Main/Api/Api.csproj] in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops

I know this question is repeating a lot but I've tried many solutions that was posted but nothing works.
So I was running the docker on Azure DevOps release pipeline, and the Agent job return me this error:

`Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Main/Api/Api.csproj]`

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT #{environment-profile}#

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Main/Api/Api.csproj", "Main/Api/"]
COPY ["Main/Domain/Domain.csproj", "Main/Domain/"]
COPY ["Side/Infra/Infra.csproj", "Side/Infra/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Main/Api/Api.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/Main/Api"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll", "--environment=#{environment-profile}#"]
```

The error is coming from this line: `RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build`

Here is my project structure:

After open .sln file:

- Main (Folder)

  - Api (Folder)

    - Api.csroj
  - Domain (Folder)

    - Domain.csproj
- Side (Folder)

  - Infra (Folder)

    - Infra.csproj

I have followed some posts in SO to put `COPY . .` after `WORKDIR "/src/Main/Api"` but it did not work as well.

Also I do not want to move my Dockerfile to root directory because I have two Dockerfile in this solution so I would like to maintain them in their respective folder. (However I still tried this, putting Dockerfile into root directory also not working...)

Furthermore, this Dockerfile is built successfully in my local. Only failed in Azure DevOps release pipeline. I have set the path to Dockerfile in the release pipeline to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Main_CI/drop/Main/Api/Dockerfile`, as well as build context to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Main_CI/drop`.

Appreciate if anyone know what's wrong! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Corene, I noticed that **Bassam Gamal** has shared much helpful information with you. If the suggestions have helped you solve the problem, please mark his answer as the solution of this topic. It may help other people who have the similar problems when they are looking for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem eventually, which is I need to copy everything from my repo to the Artifact because the Dockerfile is finding the `Program.cs` to find the `main` method. And I only copied the `.csproj` file which makes it cannot find `Program.cs` in building the image.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker build step, you need to control the context the docker build command is executed. In this case should be root folder, if it's **, then it's using the same dockerfile folder, for root remove them or manually select the folder.

Comment: Yes my docker file path is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Main_CI/drop/Main/Api/Dockerfile`

and my build context path is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Main_CI/drop`

Comment: Two things to try, clear cache locally using 'docker system prune' and rebuild and see if it works.
Then regenerate dockerfile if you are using VS/Code maybe you did some path changes  so a module is missing a copy instruction

Comment: This one is run on Azure DevOps, does that able to clear cache? Generated dockerfile again done, all are the same except I added for ENV variables. And the `COPY . .` is in front of `WORKDIR "/src/Main/Api" `

Comment: Normally you don't have to add copy instructions, cache was to test locally if it works, I thought a layer was cached.

Comment: Locally build was successful, so I'm thinking is it Azure DevOps setting problem...

Comment: If build successed locally, did you try to run a container from the image and it worked?

Comment: The build image is failed in Azure DevOps so I do not have an image to pull and test. It fails right at the `RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build` command in Dockerfile.

Comment: I am speaking about locally, you said it builds successfully so I am asking if you tried to run a container from it?

Comment: Yes, in local I had run the image in a container and able to access the Api Swagger service in `http://localhost:8080/` after I routed the traffic to 8080 port because port 80 is not available in my local. Is it the port issue? Because in Dockerfile it was specified `EXPOSE 80`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225957/discussion-between-bassam-gamal-and-corene).